# Can't debug web applications in visual studio 2013

Tags: asp.net, debugging, visual-studio-2013

I created sample web application in visual studio 2013 and put break point, but when running solution the break point get disabled. I set "debug=true" in web.config The issues is only with web applications, I can able to debug console application.

EDIT:

After clearing both windows and user temp file the break point get hit, but now I can't able to evaluate expression in quick watch. which says the variable is out of scope

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you also have debug set in toolbar drop down on top. Right-click your home page in Solution Explorer and set it as starting page, and then try again.

Set a break point on some code in the Page Load event handler of your starting page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to debug, then set on menu Build.Configuration_manager the Active_solution_configuration to Debug and the Configuration property to Debug also. If you want to Publish the application, then set this properties to Release.